# Bison printing variable from flex wrong

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

So I've got a Bison rule that looks like this:

```
VAR ID ':' INT '=' intexp ';' {printf("id is '%s'\n", $2);}
```

and I'm trying to print the value of the 'ID' using $2

when I pipe in my test code to parse

```
var x : int = 5;
```

Bison is printing:

```
id is 'x : int = 5;'
```

instead of what I want:

```
id is 'x'
```

ID is declared in my lexer as:

```
 {ID}        { yylval.id = yytext; return ID; }
```

and if I do a printf inside the lexer right here, the value of yytext is correct ('x')

And this is where I'm stuck. Using $2 prints the whole rest of the expression instead of just the specific ID and I have no idea why. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy yytext, it's an internal buffer in flex.

I.e., instead of

```
{ID}        { yylval.id = yytext; return ID; }
```

something like:

```
{ID}    {yylval.id = malloc(yyleng + 1); strcpy(yylval.id, yytext); return ID;}
```

Obviously that's not robust, since it doesn't do error checking, and you have to deal with freeing the memory in the parser that doesn't end up in a tree, and deal with freeing it from the tree, etc. But that is the basic idea.

Comment: `yylval.id = strdup(yytext);` is a lot simpler, and less accident-prone. You still need to `free` the returned value, of course.

Comment: @rici strdup is useful, but it's posix so isn't always available.  Oh, and strdup has to calculate strlen, whereas it's sitting there for free as yyleng.

Comment: @rici embedded nulls in identifiers?  brilliant!  j/k of course, they'd normally be in a symbol table, this method is more for strings anyway.